# Shell script (bash) to add or replace the license text contained within .c , .h and makefiles?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a set of *.c , *.h and Makefiles in a folder where some files contain the license text and some files don't have any license text. So I need a shell script where I can add license text if the file doesn't have any, and if license text is already there then I want to replace that with the new license text.

#### For example

```
Folder1
┣━ *.c
┣━ *.h
┣━ Folder2
┃  ┣━ *.c
┃  ┣━ *.h
┃  ┣━ Makefiles
┃  ┗━ Folder4
┗━ Folder3
   ┣━ *.c
   ┣━ *.h
   ┗━ Makefiles
```

**NOTE:** the license text will always be at the beginning of the files.

Example of existing License text:

```
# Copyright (C) 2008 Jack <abc@cba.com>

# This file is free software; as a special exception the author gives
# unlimited permission to copy and/or distribute it, with or without
# modifications, as long as this notice is preserved.
```

and new license text should be:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------

Copyright © 2014  Author Name

All rights reserved

----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

and for Makefiles it should be:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright © 2014  Author Name
#
# All rights reserved
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please include an example of your license text. What have you tried so far?

Comment: For Makefile: `# Copyright (C) year AuthorName  <author@id.com>
# License text
# License text  `                                           For `.c` and `.h` files the same format but the comment start with /* and ends with */

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. We also need to see the entire text. How can we know when it finishes? Is it always at the beginning of the file? What text if any will be before it?

Comment: @terdon : Always the license text will be at the beginning of the file.We can say, the End of the comment is end of the license text.

Comment: Why not a C/C++ program? I believe it'll be way easier to create a C/C++ script that would go through all the files in a folder appending certain text to it's first line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming bash:

```
function remove_copyright {
    printf "%s\n" 1,10d w q | ed "$1"
}

function add_copyright {
    if [[ $1 == Makefile ]]; then
        ed "$1" <<END
0i
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright © 2014  Author Name
#
# All rights reserved
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
.
w
q
END
    else
        ed "$1" <<END
0i
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------

Copyright © 2014  Author Name

All rights reserved

---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.
w
q
END
    fi
}

shopt -s nullglob globstar
for file in **/*.[ch]; do
    if grep -q '^# Copyright \(C\)' "$file"; then
        remove_copyright "$file"
    fi
    add_copyright "$file"
done
```

Comment: Yeah,the existing copyright text is same for all the files and always it will be at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 3):

This script checks, if `*.c` and `*.h` files begin with `/* Copyright (C)` and `Makefile*` files begin with `# Copyright (C)`.

If so, this script will print the copyright text specified in your `LICENCEFILE` on top of each file as a commentary.

```
#!/bin/bash
LICENCEFILE="licence"
[ ! -f "$LICENCEFILE" ] && echo "$LICENCEFILE is missing. Abort." && exit 1

for i in *.c *.h; do
    [ "$(head -c16 $i)" == "/* Copyright (C)" ] && continue

    NEWFILE="${i}.new"
    [ -f "$NEWFILE" ] && echo "Sorry, $NEWFILE already exists" && continue

    echo "/* " > "$NEWFILE"
    cat "$LICENCEFILE" >> "$NEWFILE"
    echo "*/" >> "$NEWFILE"
    cat "$i" >> "$NEWFILE"
done

for i in Makefile*; do
    [ "$(head -c15 $i)" == "# Copyright (C)" ] && continue

    NEWFILE="${i}.new"
    [ "${i#*.}" == "new" ] && continue
    [ -f "$NEWFILE" ] && echo "Sorry, $NEWFILE already exists" && continue

    while read line; do
        echo "# $line" >> "$NEWFILE"
    done < "$LICENCEFILE"
    cat "$i" >> "$NEWFILE"
done
```

Example `LICENCEFILE`:

```
Copyright (C) year AuthorName  <author@id.com>
licence text
licence text
```

`LICENCEFILE` has to contain "Copyright (C)" as the first 13 characters.

The above script produces `*.new` files that are the modified versions of all found `*.c` `*.h` and `Makefile*` files. After you've verified that the script produced correct output, just overwrite the old files with:

```
for i in *.new; do mv "$i" "${i%.new}"; done
```

Comment: I tried this script,but it is not working, it is just creating *.c.New , *.h.new and *.new.Makefile.

Comment: Output after running this script:

Comment: these `*.new` files should contain the modified versions of your files. That was a security feature so that you can check the modified files, before you overwrite them with `for i in *.new; do mv "$i" "${i%.new}"; done`. Keep in mind that you have to specify a `LICENCEFILE`, which has to be in the same folder as the script.

Comment: but the new file contains only /* */

Comment: have you created a file named `licence`? delete all created files before you start the script again `rm *.new`.

Comment: Yeah I did,and the content inside that file is my new license text

Comment: Did you try solution? http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140487/72471